# sed extract digits

Tags: sed, extract, digits

I try to extract digits with sed:

```
echo hgdfjg678gfdg kjg45nn | sed 's/.*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g'
```

but result is:
5
How to extract: 678 and 45?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Great article about sed [~here~](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) !

Answer (score 22):

The problem is that the `.` in `.*` will match digits as well as non-digits, and it keeps on matching as long as it can -- that is as long as there's one digit left unconsumed that can match the `[0-9]`.

Instead of extracting digits, just delete non-digits:

```
echo hgdfjg678gfdg kjg45nn | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'
```

or even

```
echo hgdfjg678gfdg kjg45nn | tr -d -c 0-9
```

Comment: In sed, probably want to replace non-digits with a single space, so the original groupings of digits can be maintained.

Comment: Note, that `sed 's/[^0-9]//g'` will not cut off new line characters (important, when you filtering multiline strings), however `tr -d -c 0-9` will do

Answer (score 9):

You may use grep with option -o for this:

```
$ echo hgdfjg678gfdg kjg45nn | grep -E -o "[0-9]+"
678
45
```

Answer (score 3):

Or use `tr`:

```
$ echo hgdfjg678gfdg kjg45nn | tr -d [a-z]
678 45
```

Comment: You can also use `tr -d [:alpha:]` to handle capital letters, too.

Answer (score 2):

`.*` in `sed` is greedy. And there are no `non-greedy` option AFAIK.
(You must use `[^0-9]*` in this case for non-greedy matching. But this works only once, so you will get only `678` without `45`.)

If you must use only `sed`, it would not be easy to get the result.
I recommend to use gnu’s `grep`

```
$ echo hgdfjg678gfdg kjg45nn | grep -oP '\d+'
678
45
```

If you really want to stick to `sed`, this would be one of many possible answers.

```
$ echo hgdfjg678gfdg kjg45nn | \
sed -e 's/\([0-9^]\)\([^0-9]\)/\1\n\2/g' | \
sed -n 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p’
678
45
```